# Inserting unique values to Database from EF

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, razor-pages

I'm creating a CRUD application using Razor pages. I'm using a SQL based database. I do not want to allow a tool to have the same tool number. If possible exception handling would be ideal. Get an message where it says "Toolnumber already exists" etc.

`IDENTITY(1,1)` while editing a tool I get this error message:

> SqlException: Cannot update identity column 'ToolNumber'.

UNIQUE when I set the same toolnumber for two tools I get this error message:

> SqlException: Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ__TOOL__F63D0498394D4BBD'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.TOOL'. The duplicate key value is (1).

This is my `Tool` entity:

```
public class Tool
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "RFID Kode kreves")]
    public long ToolId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Verktøynummer kreves")]
    public int ToolNumber { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Model navn kreves")]
    [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Maksimal lengde 20 bokstaver")]
    public string? Model { get; set; }
    public bool Borrowed { get; set; }
    [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Maksimal lengde 20 bokstaver")]
    public string? Manufacturer { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Verktøy kategori kreves")]
    [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Maksimal lengde 20 bokstaver")]
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public long EmployeeId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Maksimal lengde 30 bokstaver")]
    public string? EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Maksimal lengde 20 bokstaver")]
    public string? SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateOfPurchase { get; set; }
    public int? Reminder { get; set; }
    public string? Price { get; set; }
    [StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 0, ErrorMessage = "Maksimal lengde 10 bokstaver")]
    public string? Condition { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateOfCalibration { get; set; }
    public string? CalibrationPlace { get; set; }
    public string? PhotoPath { get; set; }        
}
```

This is my Add method:

```
public Tool Add(Tool newTool)
{
    context.TOOL.Add(newTool);
    context.SaveChanges();
    return newTool;
}
```

This is my Update method:

```
public Tool Update(Tool updatedTool)
{
    var tool = context.TOOL.Attach(updatedTool);
    tool.State = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Modified;
    context.SaveChanges();
    return updatedTool;
}
```

Comment: What's the point of having both `ToolID` and `ToolNumber`? What's the *actual* key? If it's `ToolID`, why use `IDENTITY` with  `ToolNumber`? In fact, why use `ToolNumber` at all?

Comment: Have you considered using a sequence for `ToolNumber` ?  Are you using SQL Server?  And if using a sequence, exception handling (for duplicates) wouldn't be required.

Comment: Hi so the company this project is for. They wanted ToolNumber and TooID. The other student I'm working with wanted ToolId to be the Primary Key. ToolNumber is just a number to separate two tools who is the same model. ToolId is the RFID tag number this tool will have.

Answer (score 1):

You could validate if there's any tool in the db before add/update with the same ToolNumber and throw a custom exception.

```
public class DuplicatedException : Exception
{
    public DuplicatedException()
    {
    }

    public DuplicatedException(string message)
        : base(message)
    {
    }

    public DuplicatedException(string message, Exception inner)
        : base(message, inner)
    {
    }
}
```

Methods:

```
public Tool Add(Tool newTool)
{
    if (context.TOOL.FirstOrDefault(t => t.ToolNumber == newTool.ToolNumber))
        throw new DuplicatedException("Toolnumber already exists");

    context.TOOL.Add(newTool);
    context.SaveChanges();
    return newTool;
}

public Tool Update(Tool updatedTool)
{
    if (context.TOOL.FirstOrDefault(t => t.ToolNumber == updatedTool.ToolNumber && t.ToolId != updatedTool.ToolId))
        throw new DuplicatedException("Toolnumber already exists");

    var tool = context.TOOL.Attach(updatedTool);
    tool.State = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Modified;
    context.SaveChanges();
    return updatedTool;
}
```

Comment: I get this error: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'ToolInventory.Models.Tool' to 'bool' ToolInventory.Services D:\Programmer\Skole\Final\CaverionLagerSystem - Admin\ToolInventory.Services\SQLToolRepository.cs 23 Active